# Unable to make an image non-right-clickable with absolute element in flex div

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with disabling "right click/save image as" for images.

It works as expected when I remove flex style.

In the current example it is very confusing, not just the second square is not "protected" for right click at all but the first one is only partly protected, the transparent rectangle is "clickable" at the right side.

I would love to fix this code instead of using another solution.

Code:

```css
.post-thumbnail {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 768px;
}

.post-thumbnail:before {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    content: "\020";
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    background: #232649;
    opacity: 0.8;
    z-index: 5;
}

.post-thumbnail img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li>
<div style="display: flex; justify-content: center;">
    <div class="post-thumbnail">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_forest.jpg" width="300" height="200">
    </div>
    <div class="post-thumbnail">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_forest.jpg" width="300" height="200">
    </div>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Where's the code you're using to restrict the clicks?

Comment: It's the ".post-thumbnail:before " styling.

Comment: Ya that's not going to restrict clicks, you'll want javascript somewhere for this.

Comment: It works with .post-thumbnail:before  width and height set to 200%, but I don't like "200%".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need javascript for this, something like the example below.

```js
// Remove right-click for images.
const images = document.querySelectorAll('img');

images.forEach((img) => img.addEventListener('contextmenu', event => event.preventDefault()));
```

```css
.post-thumbnail {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 768px;
}

.post-thumbnail:before {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    content: "\020";
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    background: #232649;
    opacity: 0.8;
    z-index: 5;
}

.post-thumbnail img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li>
<div style="display: flex; justify-content: center;">
    <div class="post-thumbnail">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_forest.jpg" width="300" height="200">
    </div>
    <div class="post-thumbnail">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_forest.jpg" width="300" height="200">
    </div>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
```

Or a purely html/CSS approach that won't actually solve your issue.

```css
.post-thumbnail {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 768px;
}

.post-thumbnail:after {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    content: "";
    opacity: 0.8;
    z-index: 1;
    user-select: none;
}

.post-thumbnail img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
  <div style="display: flex; justify-content: center;">
      <div class="post-thumbnail">
          <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_forest.jpg" width="300" height="200">
      </div>
      <div class="post-thumbnail">
          <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_forest.jpg" width="300" height="200">
      </div>
  </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks but I would like to perfect my initial idea if possible before I pick an alternative.

Comment: See updated 2nd answer, is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Chris, I appreciate your time. Your javascript option is working, CSS option is not working for me. Still there is a reason why I want to stick with my initial code , 1. user experience with totally disabled right click is not the best, 2. I am afraid of what impact to SEO that javascript can possibly have since the main content of the website are images.

Comment: Yea that's why the js way is the best option, different browsers might interpret the other way differently....however no, it will not negatively effect SEO, you can [google it](https://www.google.com/search?q=does+disabling+right+click+affect+seo) to confirm.

Comment: I will use "user-select: none;", it doesn't work in your code for some strange reason but it works where it should work. CSS solution is not reliable but it's not a big problem in my case.